# Can only enable HDR when using one monitor, despite both monitors being identical

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, amd-graphics-card, hdr

I finally bit the bullet and upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11 Version 21H2 (OS build 22000.1042) just so I could have functioning HDR on my system, but it seems like that isn't going to happen easily.

I have two identical HDR-enabled monitors (LG 27GN800-B) connected via HDMI 2.0 cables to my RX 470 (which supports HDR and has HDMI 2.0 ports). Currently I have the displays set to extend mode. Turning on HDR in this mode results in the switch immediately turning back off.

However, if I set it to only use one monitor (doesn't matter which one), I can then set that monitor to use HDR. The colors look washed out, but I feel like that's fixable via calibration if I could get it working reliably. If I switch to individual monitors and turn on HDR for both, I can no longer switch back to extend mode; it immediately reverts to single monitor mode.

After seeing [this post on Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hdr-cant-be-turned-on-with-dual-monitors-help/073d8cc3-317d-46fb-88bc-46ff44fbf4eb), I tried downgrading my GPU driver from 22.5.1 to 21.8.2 as suggested. This let me turn on HDR with both monitors enabled in extend mode, but after doing that, the secondary monitor was just black (but on), and system performance/responsiveness became unusable. It was kind of like input lag, but sometimes input wouldn't register at all, and it was like everything was stuttering. Searching for this just came up with Reddit posts about HDR causing stuttering in some games, but this was the entire Windows desktop with no game open. So, I upgraded all the way to version 22.9.1 of the driver, and the result is the same as with 22.5.1.

I don't think it's a hardware or HDMI cable problem because I can enable HDR for both monitors independently, but I can't use both at the same time.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I've spent several days trying to figure this out and I'm all out of ideas. I am happy to provide any logs or other information, just let me know what to grab. I'm completely lost here and any help would be much appreciated :)

P.S.: if the answer is "don't use an AMD GPU, their drivers suck", I will probably have a new NVIDIA GPU soon, but I have HDR photos I need to process in the mean time!

Comment: Especially if you have photos to edit, switch off HDR & calibrate your screen properly instead. Windows 'HDR' is a horrible guesswork algorithm with no defined profile. If your displays can do it, use P3. If not, Adobe 98. If you're working to sRGB, then there is absolutely no point in Windows' "HDR" at all - everything everyone sees is just wrong. This is a structure to avoid like the plague.

Comment: Meh, it's an sRGB display with snake oil to keep the gamers happy. HDR10 is a video format, no use for stills. https://www.lg.com/hk_en/monitor/lg-27gn800-b